# How to implement this print button?

Tags: website-design, search, search-results, printing

I have been asked to add a new print feature to a website.

## Current setup

- The page allows users to search for information
- Information is displayed in a table
- Each table row can be expanded to provide additional details
- Users can print a list of results (even if rows are expanded the additional info will not print; only a list will print)

**Table of results:**

[image]

**Additional details when row expanded:**

[image]

## Ideal setup

A new printing feature is to be able to print only those results that are starred (*including* the additional details).

I'm working on how to implement that in the UI. It would work like this:

- User lands on page. Only one print button is shown (print list)
- User clicks star to favourite a result. Second print button shows (print details).
- If user unclicks all stars the 'print details' button will hide again

Example of second button:

[image]

## Question

Is this a good approach?

The development will take me some time, and I'd like to make sure this implementation isn't awful.

Any feedback sincerely appreciated!

Comment: 1. Do the favourites play another role, apart from selecting results for printing? 2. Is there a use case for printing list without any details? 3. Is there a use case for printing multiple result's details?

Comment: @JakubTutaj 1. Yes, favourites are added to a user's file and can be retrieved later 2. The lists can be quite long, and the details contain images - printing just the list is useful for some people 3. Being able to print the details on selected results is a way to make more detailed comparisons I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, based on 1 & 3, shouldn't printing favourites with/without details be a part of the page where User focuses on the favourites only? It seems that printing details of results is not a part of the customer journey (or their goal) when making search. You could probably come up with a better solution, once job to be done by the User is more understood - as you mentioned maybe it's for comparison, but maybe there's something else to it, or only part of the detailed information is critical to be compared and then printed etc.

Comment: @JakubTutaj Thanks for your input. You make a good point. I think NGAFD's answer below is a great way for the user to decide exactly what they want to print.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flow should be something like this.

1. The user clicks on 'print list'.
2. After that, he selects his options, just like a regular print setup.
3. The user confirms and prints.

[image]

Now, based on the comments I know the favourites have another function besides only selecting so I'm not suggesting a change to that.

Here's how I would design the second step. See image below.

It's a dialog with a clear title, explaining text and options (with a default. Think of what the default option should be).

[image]

The only problem with this flow could be that a user clicks on print, sees the option to only print favourites and has to cancel and re-select. Maybe It's an idea to have a 'quick tip' text next to the print button. Use this for first time users or as a 'tutorial popup' perhaps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a great implementation. Would it be an idea to have that 'quick tip' pop up when a user favourites a result?

Comment: I think so, yes. Maybe you can position it as a fun 'hey! did you know...' kind of message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are specific about using two separate CTA's then you can make slight changes to your current UI as indicated in below mock up.

[image]

If no item is starred then you can keep that CTA link/button disabled.

Although I feel NGAFD's approach is better. hence in that case you can keep single print drop down where in user can select appropriate options for printing either complete list(by default) or starred item list. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That layout definitely makes the UI cleaner, and I think you are right to have the CTA disabled rather than hidden completely.

Comment: glad I could help :)